# Need to break up a large file into smaller files to send via sp_sendsqlmail

Tags: sql-server-2016, dynamic-sql, database-mail

I have created a job to send a "report" to someone (actually two reports). My issue is that the query is returning some 150K+ rows of data (no lobs or xml or anything, so not large rows), but sp_sendmail is balking at sending that large of a file (apparently -- no job failure, but no email is generated. Nothing at all in the log). So, I think I need to break this into smaller files to send, but need a little help in doing that programmatically.

Comment: Under database mail configuration, there is an option to view or change system parameters - take a look at the maimum file size in bytes to ensure you aren't exceeding that value

Comment: Hi Scott -- thank you, but I don't want to necessarily change that parameter as mail server also has parameters for file size. I'm pretty sure I just need to break this up into manageable chunks.